# How to find all questions without any answers with Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, eager-loading

I have two entities Question and Answer with appropriate relationships.

I want an optimized way (less resource) to find all questions (only id and title) without answers with doctrine.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller…

Using the QueryBuilder:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Question');
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('Question');
$query = $qb
    ->select('DISTINCT Question.id, Question.title')
    ->leftJoin('Question.answers', 'Answer', $qb->expr()->isNull('Answer.id'))
    ->getQuery();

$questions = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Or DQL (partial objects:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("select partial Question.{id,title} 
                           from MyApp\Domain\Question Question 
                           left join Question.answers Answer 
                           where Answer.id is NULL");

$questions = $query->getResult();
```

The query builder will return an array while the DQL will return **partial objects**.

See:

- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html
- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html